# Can I create ngrx effect outside of a class, like in redux-observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

This is an ngrx effect taken from the official docs.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
  @Effect() login$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.ofType('LOGIN')
    // Map the payload into JSON to use as the request body
    .map(toPayload)
    .mergeMap(payload =>
      this.http.post('/auth', payload)
        // If successful, dispatch success action with result
        .map(data => ({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: data }))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
        .catch(() => of({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED' }))
    );

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private actions$: Actions
  ) {}      
}
```

Can I make it look more like this?

```
import {actions$, registerEffect} from ...


const login$: Observable<Action> = actions$.ofType('LOGIN')
    // Map the payload into JSON to use as the request body
    .map(toPayload)
    .mergeMap(payload =>
      this.http.post('/auth', payload)
        // If successful, dispatch success action with result
        .map(data => ({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: data }))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
        .catch(() => of({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED' }))
    );


registerEffect(login$);
```

Without the class and the angular references?

The idea is to reduce(ha!) the coupling between the effects and the angular framework. And I see no technical reason for that to not be possible.

Comment: Quick question. Do you just want to not use DI like in the `AuthEffects` class or you don't want to use `EffectsModule.run` function either?

Comment: I have no problem with the `EffectsModule`. I just don't want the class and the angular DI integration.

Comment: What do you mean by "reduce the coupling between the effects and the angular framework"? Are you trying to use ngrx store/effects outside of an angular project? IIRC They tried to remove the angular dependency before to make it an independent project, but then they reverted that decision.

Comment: That said, it's possible to declare and wire up effects within an angular project without the effect code referencing angular's `Injectable` for DI, but I'm not sure what manually wiring that up buys you, since the rest of ngrx wires itself up via DI.

Comment: However, if you just want to implement effect functions outside of the class, but are willing to declare them on a DI'd class, that's much easier and is probably a good idea. Just keep the `@Injectable` Effects class, and define each effect method like: `@Effect() myEffectFnProp$ = someEffectFnDefinedElsewhere(maybeSomeInitParamsToo);`